# How long has "looney" (meaning "lunatic") been in use?

Tags: etymology

How long has *looney* been used as an abbreviation of *lunatic*? Is it a recent addition or something substantially older?

Comment: And, of course, [Looney Tunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looney_Tunes) goes back to 1930.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/612919/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *loony* has an entry in [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=loony). It says:

> 1853, Amer.Eng., short for lunatic, but also infl. by loon (2), which is noted for its wild cry and method of escaping from danger. Slang loony bin "insane asylum" is from 1919. Looney left in ref. to holders of political views felt to be extreme is from 1977.

However, the OED disagrees and instead dates the term to 1872, from the short story ["An Heiress of Red Dog"](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/13495/) by Bret Harte. The story says,

> You're that looney sort of chap that lives over yonder, ain't ye?

I'm more inclined to believe the OED (thank you Nicholas for bringing this up!), so with a date of 1872 the phrase is not substantially old.

Comment: I don't know where EtymOnline gets the 1853 date (and I'm not saying it's wrong), but the earliest citation in the OED is from 1872, in Bret Harte's short story "An Heiress of Red Dog": "You're that looney sort of chap that lives over yonder, ain't ye?" The story can be read online here: http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/13495/

Comment: I edited my answer -- thank you for providing me with what I think is a much more accurate source.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some references **older than [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=loony)'s 1853**. I think they're are used as an abbreviation of lunatic.

[The cabinet of instruction,literature,and amusement: Volume 1, 1829](http://books.google.com/books?id=gGxIAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA723&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=h7FHTs3aBsn4sgai3-31Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBTigAQ#v=onepage&q=%22looney%22&f=false):

> A country looney, soft as boiled peas, went to a neighboring village
>   one Sunday last autumn, partly on business and partly on pleasure. As
>   Sunday is Cupid's market day, he, to his inexpressible joy, fell in
>   with a charming damsel, ...

[Sea songs, tales, etc. by Ned Halyard, 1849](http://books.google.com/books?id=F98MAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA270&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=xqVHTtLcLoSWswbz9cC5CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=17&ved=0CH8Q6AEwEDisAg#v=onepage&q=looney&f=false):

> What's done is done, — and I am *done*
>
> Brown by a thundering looney ;
>
> By jove, it would be capital sport
>
> If the *dish'd* could run off with the spooney.

---

Here's some references **older than the OED's 1872**, which are definitely abbreviations of lunatic.

[Advocate and family guardian, Volume 31, 1865](http://books.google.com/books?id=93QXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA274&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=4qpHTpjHF4vzsgbBxKieDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=19&ved=0CIwBEOgBMBI4wAI#v=onepage&q=looney&f=false):

> Well, if that ain't looney ; I declare, girls are always getting some
>   crochet or other in their heads," said Harry, contemptuously. " If
>   they never get a worse oue than this," said Mrs. Lane, " there's not
>   much harm done.

[Harper's magazine: Volume 35, 1867](http://books.google.com/books?id=jHcCAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA641&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=061HTqO3FYrWsgaa-sGiCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=15&ved=0CHMQ6AEwDjigAQ#v=onepage&q=%22looney%22&f=false):

> I told him he was a looney to suggest it, and went away seriously contemplating the idea of changing my banker.

[The mimic stage: a series of dramas, comedies, burlesques, and farces, for public exhibitions and private theatricals](http://books.google.com/books?id=fkxAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=GatHTqQ5hvayBpPnrKYJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=12&ved=0CGUQ6AEwCzisAg#v=onepage&q=%22looney%22&f=false), 1869:

> Ha ! ha ! ha ! this Romeo, silly looney,
>
> Has, on old Capulet's daughter, got quite spooney ;
>
> And now to wed her he is nothing loth.
>
> Ha ! ha ! he'll find my fingers in the broth.

[Rural and city life : or: The fortunes of the Stubble family, 1870](http://books.google.com/books?id=gNsNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA140&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=GatHTqQ5hvayBpPnrKYJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAjisAg#v=onepage&q=%22looney%22&f=false):

> "... Ho, ho, ho ! what a billy looney he must be to give that money for a
>   hape ov ould rub- bidge ! Ha, ha, ha ! his wife wud give him beans
>   when he took the tubs home, I 'll ingage." " There, there, that'll do,
>   Biddy. You have laughed quite enough. ..."

[Dublin University magazine: a literary and political journal, Volume 77, 1871](http://books.google.com/books?id=hB-ZGZw_F5AC&q=%22looney%22&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=da5HToLYOsPWsgbjms23Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBTg8):

> Gazing on the intruder, whom he did not at first recognise, he
>   faltered : " You looney ! ... Are you mad, Looney ?" "Blood and
>   thunder! To be sure I am ; or I should be if I let you and Colonel
>   O'Dywer have it all your own way. ...

[The West Point scrap book: a collection of stories, songs, and legends of the United States military academy, 1871](http://books.google.com/books?id=U6FDAAAAIAAJ&q=%22looney%22&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=4a5HTpbnAc7dsgaygonEBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBDgo):

> ... and my only regret is that I am not in a " Lunatic Asylum," for
>   there I could " while the fearfully weary hours away," in watching the
>   eccentric performances of individuals more " looney " than myself; but
>   under the existing ...

[The Alaska herald: Volumes 4-6, 1871](http://books.google.com/books?id=mPkUAAAAYAAJ&q=%22looney%22&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=4a5HTpbnAc7dsgaygonEBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAzgo):

> We are sorry the author of the following story did'not send us his
>   name, as some people are uncharitable enough to suggest that two-
>   thirds of the tales of this kind are fabrications, and the remainder
>   the product of " looney " fancies ...

[History of a trip to the great Saginaw Valley, June, 1871, by invitation of the Fort Wayne, Muncie, and Cincinnati railroad, and with the co-operation of the Bee line, Fort Wayne, Jackson and Saginaw, and Jackson, Lansing and Saginaw railroad companies, 1871](http://books.google.com/books?id=glEVAAAAYAAJ&q=%22looney%22&dq=%22looney%22&hl=en&ei=ka9HTpPAHIrXsgas78GjBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=20&ved=0CH0Q6AEwEzgU):

> "Where's the wilderness?" I asked, as we made our way through smiling villages and luxuriant farms. What a looney I must have seemed to the engineer, who laughed, but
>   made no talk.

---

Finally, here's an 1885 definition of **luny**.

[The progressive dictionary of the English language: a supplementary wordbook to all the leading dictionaries of the United States and Great Britain, 1885](http://books.google.com/books?id=vulBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA295&dq=loony&hl=en&ei=hrRHTuvwLIaWswassqykCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFYQ6AEwCDg8#v=onepage&q=loony&f=false):

> **Luny** a. Unsound in mind ; crazy; loony. [Low. U. S.]

Comment: Just edited to show some possible references from before 1853.

Answer (score 0):

"**Looney**" is also a surname dating back into the 1400s in the Isle of Man and the 1500s in Ireland.  The earliest it is found in the U.S. is 1724 in Chester County, PA, where Manxman Robert Looney and his sons are first found on the county tax roles (see "Most Distinguished Characters on the American Frontier: Robert Looney" by Madge Looney Crane and her son, Phillip Crane).

Also, I believe a family of 12 brothers arrived in Boston, MA, later in the 1700s and have, mostly, stayed in that area.  Looneys across the U.S. are, then, more likely to be Manx in origin as those Loones moved into Virginia then exploded across the continent.

The meaning of the name has been said to be slightly different in Man than in Ireland, but the base is Celtic so is similar.

o  Manx is said to be something akin to Captains of God's Army and, as late as the mid-1800s, all Looneys in Man were found residing on church properties.

o  Irish is said to be more akin to Champions of the Army of God or Leaders of God's Army.  Early Irish variants (or origins) were Luinigh and Loinghes.  A later branch of the family moved to Scotland and became O'Looney.

Robert Looney gave his name to a creek (Looneys Mill Creek) that flows into the James River in western Virginia.  He also founded Ft. Looney at that intersection (later renamed Ft. Fauquier during the Revolutionary War) and Looneys Ferry - the first crossing of the James River.

His son, Absalom, gave the name to a gap in the mountains west of Cumberland Gap called Looneys Gap.

Comment: Ed, thank you for this answer, although I fail to see how it relates to the use of *looney* as an abbreviation for *lunatic,* as this six year old question asks. We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Sources related to your answer could valuable